# Problem with Ethernet connection on PC, integrated network card (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: networking, ethernet

In the network manager : unplugged cable (but cable allright), I dissconect and connect - dont solve the problem.
If `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` - I have this:

```
Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd RTL-8129 [10ec:8129] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Coreo Inc RTL8111/8168 PCIe Gigabit Ethernet (misconfigured) [11ec:8129]
Kernel driver in use: 8139too
```

Comment: This is interesting. A wrong driver is loaded. Try to run `sudo modprobe -r 8139too && sudo modprobe r8169`. 9 is not a typo!

Comment: Thank you for advice, but it only remove '8139too'(eth0), and r8169 don't appear like eth0 =(

Comment: And also please add output of `uname -a`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the driver. Do in terminal.

```
sudo modprobe -r 8139too
echo "10ec 8129" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/new_id
sudo modprobe -r r8169
sudo modprobe r8169
```

If your network cards starts working, I will add how to make it permanent after reboot.

Comment: `uname -a`  = `Linux denis 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.  when I run `echo "10ec 8129" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/new_id` I get `No such file or directory`